# autoload pagination not working been urls been cleaned through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination

i am using auto load pagination method on my page , but when using htaccess to clean the url the pagination stops working , even the data does not appear .  if i remove pagination method everything is fine , or if i remove htaccess everything works fine .

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var busy = false;
  var limit = 10
  var offset = 0;

  function displayRecords(lim, off) {  
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      async: false,


        url: "getresult.php", 
       data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off + "&city=<?php echo $_GET['city'] ; ?>",



      cache: false,

      success: function(html) {
        $("#results").append(html);
        window.busy = false;
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // start to load the first set of data
    if (busy == false) {
      busy = true;
      // start to load the first set of data
      displayRecords(limit, offset);
    }


    $(window).scroll(function() {
      // make sure u give the container id of the data to be loaded in.
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#results").height() && !busy) {
        busy = true;
        offset = limit + offset;

        // this is optional just to delay the loading of data
        setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset); }, 500);

        // you can remove the above code and can use directly this function
        // displayRecords(limit, offset);

      }
    });

  });

</script>
```

this is my htaccess code :

```
    RewriteRule ^city/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ eventlist.php?city=$1
```

Comment: What url are you going to?

Comment: the main page url is eventlist.php , in this we need to filter the data by city , so the complete url is eventlist.php?city=      
the filtered data is coming on this page through ajax , the ajax url is    
url: "getresult.php", data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off + "&city=<?php echo $_GET['city'] ; ?>"

Comment: hello , if there is no one to reply , what is the fun of asking help on stackoverflow .   it should be closed